# Kendo Barcode - How to resize with script

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a Barcode that is within a partial view.  If I do not include a width and height at the beginning I get an error when rendering.

```html
@Html.Kendo().Barcode().Name("barcode-" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).Value(@Model.WidgetTagValue).Encoding(Model.barcode_symbology).Width(150).Height(150)
```

I have a resize event that tries to change it to fit the size of the parent div on page init and on window resize.

```js
function setBarcodeSize() {
        if ($('.k-barcode').length > 0) {
            $('.k-barcode').each(function () {
                var parentDivWidth = $(this).closest(".andon-widget-container").width() - 50;
                var parentDivHeight = $(this).closest(".andon-widget-container").height() - $(this).closest(".andon-widget-container").find(".andon-widget-title").height();
                $(this).css("width", $(this).width(parentDivWidth) + "px").css("height", $(this).height(parentDivHeight) + "px");
                $(this).data("kendoBarcode").redraw();
            });
        }
    }
```

The width and height of the k-barcode  are set appropriately but the size of the child  with the data-role="surface" remains at 150x150

Advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like api documentation lied about it. You have to set dimentions by `setOptions()` method to make resize/redraw work. jQuery `css()` method doesn't work.

```
var barcode = $("#barcode").data("kendoBarcode");
barcode.setOptions({width: 600});
barcode.resize();
```

Example: http://dojo.telerik.com/AgENi